# Отсутствие результата при передаче через GET данных, введенных кириллицей

Tags: php, get

При формировании запроса не получается передавать данные, введенные кириллицей. При этом запросы, введенные латиницей, выполняются.

```
<form action="parcing.php">
      <h1>Параметры поиска вакансий:</h1>
      <p class="feature">Образование</p>
      <p><input type="search" class="field" name="edu" placeholder="Техническое, экономическое etc"></p> 
      <p class="feature">Hard skills</p>
      <p><input type="search" class="field" name="hs" placeholder="Профессиональные навыки"></p> 
      <p class="feature">Soft skills</p>
      <p><input type="search" class="field" name="ss" placeholder="Социальные компетенции"></p> 
      <p><input type="submit" value="Найти"></p>
      </form>
```

php

```
$edu = $_GET['edu'];
$hs = $_GET['hs'];
$ss = $_GET['ss'];
```

Comment: Покажите пример GET запроса и как получаете эти данные в файле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urlencode` — URL-кодирование строки https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php

```
 echo '<a href="in.php?rustext='.urlencode('текст на русском языке').'">Проба</a>';
```

> Эта функция удобна, когда закодированная строка будет использоваться в запросе, как часть URL, в качестве удобного способа передачи переменных на следующую страницу.

Ну, и обратно - `urldecode` — Декодирование URL-кодированной строки https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php

Ну, и есть еще
`rawurlencode()` - URL-кодирование строки согласно RFC 3986
`rawurldecode()` - Декодирование URL-кодированной строки

Смотрим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл обработчик из примера на картинках:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$edu = $_GET['edu'];
$hs = $_GET['hs'];
$ss = $_GET['ss'];

echo $edu;
echo $hs;
echo $ss;
```

Все проходит, строка `GET` запроса формируется и получается.

С пробелами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если передаю параметры через html форму?

Comment: Код Ваш выложите, пожалуйста - и формы и обработчика.

Comment: Отредактировала

Comment: Добавил в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: )Пожалуйста, рад!